# Raspbian not on SD Card after transfering

Tags: raspbian, sd-card

I have a 16gb SD Card and wanted to put Raspbian on it. So I first formatted it wih SDFormatter then I used Win32 to transfer Raspbian to the SD Card but when I go to the SD Card there's nothing there and there's only 4gb available left even though it says it's empty. So I thought maybe that's just Windows so I put it in my Raspberry Pi and connect it and everything and it won't start. It only shows the red LED but there's nothing on the screen. Now I formatted it again but it's still 4gb and I don't know what's on it know. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

From "Raw Images", http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads:

> To use an image file, you will need to unzip it and write it to a
>   suitable (2GB or larger, 4GB or larger for Raspbian) SD card using the
>   UNIX tool dd. Windows users should use Win32DiskImager. **Do not try to
>   drag and drop or otherwise copy over the image without using dd or
>   Win32DiskImager – it won’t work.** If you’re still not clear on what to
>   do, the community on the Raspberry Pi Wiki has written a guide for
>   beginners on how to set up your SD card.

The part of the beginner's guide pertaining to Windows and disk images is [here](http://elinux.org/RPi_Easy_SD_Card_Setup#Flashing_the_SD_Card_using_Windows).